# search file in specific child folder in powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

As per requirement, search file in specific child folder and then copy to destination path. I had implemented in c#.NET earlier but now want to convert in PowerShell.

```
foreach (var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(sourcePath, specificChildFolder, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
          var pathSrc = Path.Combine(directory, "xyz.config");
          if (File.Exists(pathSrc))
          {
              File.Copy(pathSrc, pathDst, true);
              break;
          }
}
```

Comment: You can even embed your c# code into a .ps1 script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code which you can use:

```
$path = "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Config Rework\"
$destination = "c:\destination\"
foreach ($filepath in [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($path,"xyz.config","AllDirectories"))
   {
      $file = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo($filepath)

      if(Test-Path $file)
      {
        write-host $file.FullName
        copy $file $destination
        Write-Host 'Copied' $file ' to ' $destination
      }
   }
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Config Rework\xyz\xyz.config
Copied C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Config Rework\xyz\xyz.config  to  c:\destination\
```

This has looped through the child folders under C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Config Rework, checked if xyz.config exists and then copied it to the destination folder.

Note that if your directory looks as follows:

[image]

xyz.config under xyz folder will take precedence as it will loop through the child folder.